# Dense layer give me 2D array

Tags: tensorflow, keras, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am making reinforcement learning for CartPole and i meet this problem

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(8,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(2,activation = 'linear')
```

this is my model

```
state = env.reset()
print(state)


output:
[-0.00315391 -0.0150189   0.01804181  0.02032083]
```

And this is what i got for prediction of my model

```
model.predict(state)

output:
[[-0.00028523  0.00031606]
 [-0.00135828  0.00150507]
 [ 0.00500827 -0.01125371]
 [ 0.00564091 -0.01267526]]
```

Why `Dense(2,activation='linear')` receiving 2D array?

I was expecting output with (2,1) shape but why model is receiving (2,4) shape?

I found that output has relationship between output node of model and input shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of state is `(4,)`, so the model considers it as 4 samples (First dimension is the number of samples). If you want to pass 1 sample with 4 features, the shape should be `(1,4)` (1 sample, 4 features), to give you `(1,2)` (1 sample, 2 outputs).

Pass it like this:

```
model.predict(np.reshape(state,(1,-1)))

# output e.g.  
# array([[ 0.0078704 , -0.00879759]], dtype=float32) #(1,2)
```

Note that your model should be built with the inputs with 4 features (e.g. `input_shape=(4,)`), otherwise you will get error. If you are just making prediction, run your model definition again.

Answer (score 0):

You have given `4` inputs and for these `4` inputs the model is predicting `4` outputs. As your output layer has `2` neurons, hence, each of the `4` outputs has `2` values. It seems to be everything fine. And the output shape is `(4, 2)` (not `(2, 4)`).

If you are thinking how it is counted as `(4, 2)`, therefore: To find the shape of a tensor manually start from left side and now if you enter inside a single `[`, you will find `4` `1 dimensional tensor`s, therefore similarly accessing inside any of these tensors you will find again `2` `0 dimensional tensor`s (i.e, `scalar`s). As you have reached up to `0 dimensional tensor`, now stop this process. This is how it is `(4, 2)`.